# How to apply scale effect, but not on hover

Tags: html, css, animation

So I'm currently working on a memory-game project.

http://digitaljo.sh/memory-game/index.html

What I'd like to accomplish is this zoom/scale effect on the 2 matching cards as they turn green.

(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/scale-on-hover-with-webkit-transition/)

```
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

===================================

This looks like it depends on a user hovering over an element. I'd like to apply it when I determine that the 2 cards are matching.

How would I go about changing this code to accomplish that?

I've tried doing something like

```
.grow {
animation: zoom;
}

@keyframes zoom { 
    100% {
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work either. (Completely a guess as I'm not sure how css keyframes work.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the animation properties correctly.

`.grow {
animation: zoom 1s normal;
}`

and with the cards matches assign the `.grow` class to these elements.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the link you provided when 2 items match you are placing `.match` on them.

Update your `.match` class to be this:

```
.card.match {
    cursor: default;
    background: #02ccba;
    font-size: 33px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

That way when the `.match` class is set, they grow right away.

Edited to add the transition property. I think this will be exactly what you are after.